# Open new Chrome window with different profile from command line

Tags: terminal, command-line, google-chrome

I want to run a command line that opens a new chrome window with another profile.

I tested the following commands:

**Preconditions:**

- I have two profiles: `Profile 1` and `Profile 2`
- Chrome is already running with `Profile 1`

`open -a "Google Chrome.app" --args --profile-directory="Profile 2"`

The above command does nothing other than bringing focus to the currently running chrome with `Profile 1`

I also tried:

`open -a "Google Chrome.app" --args --profile-directory="Profile 2" --new-window`

The effect is the same.

I want to run a command line that opens a new chrome window with `Profile 2` while there is already a Chrome window running with `Profile 1`

Comment: Could you post the output of `"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Chrome" --help` ? The last part of Chrome can be something else too. you'd have to check.

Comment: @ankii That's the answer actually :) I was using wrong profile name. I was using wrong command, too. I should have used `"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"` instead of `open` command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the arguments to the  Google Chrome's executable directly, instead of routing them via `open --args`.

Set an alias to the executable inside Chrome app. (right click > show package contents)

```
alias chrome_cli="/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
chrome_cli --profile-directory="Profile 1" --new-window
chrome_cli --profile-directory="Profile 2" --new-window
```

Even append `--new-window` to the alias if that's used a lot.

For more help, run

```
chrome_cli --help
```

To remove alias,

```
unalias chrome_cli
```

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3773/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-alias

Comment: spaces need to be escaped. alias chrome_cli="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"