# Create a terminal command to open another user profile in chrome

Tags: macos, terminal, google-chrome, user-account, profile-manager

How can I create a terminal command to open another user's profile in Chrome?

It takes me a long time to switch between them because I have a lot of users in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

Testing with **Google Chrome** (85.0.4183.102), the following *command* in **Terminal** works for me:

```
open -na 'Google Chrome' --args --profile-directory="$PROFILE"
```

- Where `$PROFILE` is the name of the *profile* you want to open, e.g. `"Default"`, `"Profile 1"`, `"Profile 2"`, etc.
- **Note:** The `$PROFILE` is the *name* of each *folder* for each *user* in: **~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/**
- In **Google Chrome** if you open a *tab* to **chrome://version/** and look at **Profile Path:**, you'll see which *profile folder* belongs to the *user* who's *profile* you are current logged in as.

---

If you want to get details of each *profile*, you can use the third-party utility `jq` to *parse* the **~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Local State** *file* in **Terminal**, e.g.:

```
jq .profile ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Local\ State
```

You can then look at the output for e.g. `"Default"`, `"Profile 1"`, `"Profile 2"`, etc. and under each *profile* you'll see info for e.g. `"gaia_given_name":`, `"gaia_name":`, `"name":` or `"user_name":` to ascertain which *profile* belongs to whom.

I downloaded `jq` from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ and it was saved a `jq-osx-amd64` in my **Downloads** *folder*. I renamed it to `jq`, made it executable with `chmod +x jq` and moved it to `/usr/local/bin/` so it would be available in my `PATH`.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/395413/313842 it seems -n was missing here.

Comment: @anki, I do not see how your comment is relevant to my answer as my answer works as stated.